# Post Variable to PHP script

Tags: php, variables, parameters

I am unable to post a string to a PHP script by sending it as xmlhttp data. 
What I am really trying to do is reading that data which I am sending now as a hard-coded string, from another variable.

What I have now is the following code:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "test.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("name=testname");
```

This post requests executes well and the PHP script receives the content of the name parameter ($stringData = $_POST["name"]);

I am trying to replace the 'testname' string with dynamic content from a variable. So

```
VARIABLE= "someContentNotHardCoded";
xmlhttp.send("name="+ VARIABLE);
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Is it possible what I am trying to do here, to append/replace the 'testname' string with dynamic content loaded from a variable?

Comment: If you can, make use of jQuery's `$.post` to make a lot more simpler.

Comment: *but this doesn't seem to work* - What do you mean by that? Does the console show anything?

Answer (score -1):

This is possible, but with these alterations:
Variables should start with a $ sign and concatenation is done with the . sign:

```
$variable = "someContentNotHardCoded";
xmlhttp.send("name=".$variable);
```

Comment: Mark1: Thank you, this is what I am looking for ; except with JavaScript code (I am posting to a php script from JavaScript code). How can I concatenate the same way with JS please?

Comment: Ah, it is Javascript you are using. You should use a Javascript tag instead of the PHP tag.
In that case your code looks OK.
Are you sure the variable contains the correct value? Any special characters?